# jQuery form posting

Tags: jquery

I am using a short script to post from data to a PHP processing page.

```
function get(){
    $.post('data.php',{name: form.name.value},
        function(output) {
        $('#age').hide().html(output).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    );
}
```

This will only send one from input:

```
$.post('data.php',{name: form.name.value},
```

I am wondering how do I alter the script to send more then one ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function get() {
   $.post('data.php', $('form').serialize(),
     function(output){
      $('#age').hide().html(output).fadeIn(1000);
   });
}
```

This assumes you want to send all form inputs. Alternatively, you could replace that with an object literal such as...

```
{
    name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
    age: $('#age').val()
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Very helpful and thanks for fixing up the code. I'm still getting my head around how it all works here.

Answer (score 1):

use id on your form fields ex: `<input type="text" id="firstname"> <input type="text" id="lastname">`

```
$.post('data.php',{"name":$('#firstname').val(),"lastname":$('#lastname').val()},function(data){
   do stuff like update the table or something..
});
```

Comment: @ ricky Thanks a lot mate. That helped me even more with getting this script working.